# How can i specify the correct placement of tooltip?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

I'm detecting when a text is too long to show, so if it is long, i reduce them using CSS and put a tooltip containing the whole text, but if it isn't long, make it green.
Ocurres the following:

[image]

It puts in center of the entirely text, not in the shorted text. How can i put in center but in the shorted text, not in the long text?

If you want all of my code, it's here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
$(function() {
  $('.txt').each(function(i) {
    if (isEllipsisActive(this)) {
      $(this).attr("data-original-title", $(this).text());
    } else $(this).css({
      'color': 'green'
    });
  });
});

function isEllipsisActive(e) {
  return (e.offsetWidth > 95);
}
```

```css
.demo {
  max-width: 95px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Hover over meeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a>
  </div>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Hover over meeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick idea, not yet finalized, why not use jquery to shorten the text instead of css? with css, your a tag is still at full width instead of 95px, so the tooltip is getting that width to calculate the position, if you change the size of the text with jquery first, it will have the correct width on a tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
$(function() {
  $('.txt').each(function(i) {
    if (isEllipsisActive(this)) {
      $(this).attr("data-original-title", $(this).text());
      $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,10)+" ..."); /* shorten text */
    } else $(this).css({
      'color': 'green'
    });
  });
});

function isEllipsisActive(e) {
  return (e.offsetWidth > 95);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Hover over meeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a>
  </div>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Hover over meeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</a>
  </div>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top">Hover over</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data',$(this).html());
    })
})
```

```css
.demo {
    position: relative;
}

a {
    width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

a[data-toggle]:hover:before {
    content: attr(data);
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    padding: 0 2px;
    color: orange;
    top: -14px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

a[data-toggle]:hover:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '\25BC';
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="toggle" data-placement="top">Hover over me, I am first A tag</a>
  </div>
  <div class="demo">
    <a class="txt" href="#" data-toggle="toggle" data-placement="top">Hover over me, I am second A tag</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: GREAT, THANKS! Another of your code, looking at this "a[data-toggle]:hover:after{ left: 50px; }", it puts in 50px, and in your example is centered, because "a" is 100px, but what happens if i increment the width of "a"? How can i detect the half with of "a" and put it in left css property? Thanks for your time

Comment: I say that because i'm making an app that can show the everything responsive, and you know that sizes are different in each device. THANKS AGAIN :')

Comment: @ChristopherCoriaVásquez , you are welcome, for it ,you can use of jvascript,but easy way is use of `left:0px` for all states.